# Is there a Trie equivalent data structure in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, trie

I am looking for trie built-in implementation in .Net framework.
Is there something similar to Trie in .Net data structures?

Comment: What do you need to actually do? What do you need the trie for?

Comment: To make an efficient search implementation. I need to count stored strings which StartsWith specific string.

Comment: https://github.com/gmamaladze/trienet

Comment: also this may be of help http://www.glennslayden.com/code/c-sharp/trie